# ACTION_BATTERY_LOW not being fired from manifest?

Tags: android, battery

Does `action_battery_low` allow being fired from the manifest because I thought it did?

Here is my manifest for it:

```
<reciever android:name=".BatteryReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
    </intent-filter>
</reciever>
```

But it never gets fired when I get the low battery warning from the system. Can this only  be fired explicitly?

Comment: It's receiver not reciever. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your question has led to great confusion. First of all you should answer the comment by @Ahsen - how would your manifest work with `<reciever>` tag ? There is no such tag. Second your accepted answer is wrong ! Please correct those

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D clearly its a typo, this question is 2 years old, I dont go back and check to make sure all my accepted answers are correct

Comment: No prob - it's just that it has caused a lot of confusion cause people were quoting the accepted answer and saying : "see `.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` can't be registered in the manifest ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14133752/281545)). Anyway - will delete my comments soon ;) - I suggest you edit the `reciever android:name` but leave the `BatteryReciever` as that was your problem probably

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The original question states that the receiver does not receive intents. This is because the receiver was declared as `<reciever>` rather than `<receiver>`. Had the receiver element been declared correctly, it would have worked.

Another major source of confusion is the fact that [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorLevel) incorrectly references `"android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"` and `"android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY"`. There is an existing [Android Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36712) for this documentation error, but you should be aware that some of the comments on that issue are misleading.

Instead, the receiver's actions must be `"android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"` and `"android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY"`. When referencing these actions from Java source, you may use the constants [android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW) and [android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY) which are defined correctly.

Unfortunately Reto Meier also incorrectly defines the action in [A Deep Dive Into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html). An issue [has been filed](http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/issues/detail?id=3) for this as well.

Comment: The Android docs and this answer were both incorrect so I'm going to fix the answer. The <intent-filter> action must be android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW, not android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW. In code you may use the android.content.Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW constant which is correctly defined as "android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW".

Answer (score 2):

From my own testing, I ran into the same issue and solution as GeoBio Boo

But then I took a closer look at my code and noticed that I was filtering on the action android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW as described in the docs: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

In reality, the action is android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW (no ACTION_).  Once I made this change, I was able to register the receiver in the Manifest and receive the event successfully (tested through emulator's power capacity command)

Comment: Thank you, this actually works, the Documentation states that the action is available via the manifest. But only by removing the "ACTION_", you can register the receiver using the full string, just not in the manifest, very odd.

Answer (score 1):

*Disregard the permission suggestion in this answer, it is incorrect.*

You might have request permission in order to catch the `BATTERY_LOW` action.
Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>` to your manifest.

Also, you can place multiple actions within the same intent-filter such as:

```
<reciever android:name=".BatteryReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
    </intent-filter>
</reciever>
```

Comment: You could try registering it through a Service for example, like: `BatteryReceiver receiver = new BatteryReceiver(); IntentFilter inf = new IntentFilter(); inf.addAction("android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"); registerReceiver(receiver, inf);`

Comment: `reciever` ? did you try it ? also `android.permission.BATTERY_STATS` is not needed

Answer (score 1):

You need to programatically register for `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`. I spent a very long time trying to figure this out, and realized that registering it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` does not work.

In other words, in your onResume() or onCreate() call:
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));

You do NOT need the `BATTERY_STATS` permission.

Comment: If your targetSdkVersion is greater than or equal to 26 and running on device oreo or above, then you will have to register and unregister the receiver programmatically due to background limitations. In this case simply declaring it in manifest does not work.

Answer (score -1):

your manifest call is correct, what about your receiver?

according Reto Meier in his legendary [Deep Dive Into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html), you should use:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.PowerStateChangedReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"/>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and your receiver activity should check

```
boolean batteryLow = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
```

i took it one step beyond and listen to 5 battery related events:

```
    <receiver android:name=".ReceiverBatteryLevel">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and then receive them like this (abbreviated, fill in the end)

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class ReceiverBatteryLevel extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "TGbattery";

    int scale = -1;
    int level = -1;
    int voltage = -1;
    int temp = -1;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"battery Receiver was called now");
        String deviceUuid = "INVALID_IMEI";

        boolean batteryLow = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
        boolean batteryOK = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY);
        boolean batteryPowerOn = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        boolean batteryPowerOff = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        boolean batteryChange = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();

            // register SHUTDOWN event
        try {
                level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
                voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);

                Log.d(TAG,intentAction+"   batteryChange="+batteryChange+"   flagLo="+batteryLow+"  batteryOK="+batteryOK+"  batteryPowerOn="+batteryPowerOn+"  batteryPowerOff="+batteryPowerOff+"\n  level="+level+"  temp="+temp+"  scale="+scale+"  voltage="+voltage);
        } // catch etc
    }
 }
```

must confess that i dont like the BatteryManager results.  any criticism is welcome.

Comment: Your code snippet is missing `}` and does not compile - amend it