# how to start application on some external event?

Tags: android

I have an application say xyz installed in my mobile, I want this application to start when battery state is low ( like 10 or 15 % ) left.

I don't have any idea how to start application when some external event or intern.

Answer (score 4):

You have to have a recevier with the  BATTERY_LOW intent filter.

```
 <receiver android:name=".my_receiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And this is your receiver

```
public class my_receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra( "level", 0 );
       //...your code to start an activity 
    }
}
```

Also, from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393651/action-battery-low-not-being-fired-from-manifest), registering for BATTERY_LOW in your manifest will not work. You wll have to register it programatically as it says.