# Android: ACTION_BATTERY_LOW not triggered in emulator. Receiver registered in code, not manifest

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, batterylevel

I have seen posts where it was mentioned `registerReceiver` has to be called  (not defined in manifest) to receive `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` intent.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       //....  
      registerReceiver(new BatteryLevelReceiver(), new IntentFilter(
                                              Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));
   }
   // .......
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class BatteryLevelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = BatteryLevelReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
    }
}
```

I do not see the "onReceive" log statement in logcat. I am using emulator to simulate battery low state, using `telnet 5554` and executing `power capacity 10`. I do see the battery status changing in the emulator but no intent triggered.

Also if I have to call `registerReceiver()` inside an activity and I do not call `unregisterReceiver` on `onStop` or `onDestroy`, is it okay? If not okay, how will I register for a receiver to receive system intents even when my app is not in foreground? (Apart from using manifest).

Comment: +1 for good formatted question. :)

Comment: Just for fun, you might try checking for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED instead of ACTION_BATTERY_LOW. Perhaps capacity 10 isn't low enough to trigger ACTION_BATTERY_LOW.

Comment: see my answer below, it works fine for me. I set the battery to 1.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that:

1. you are setting the "Charger connection" to "NONE"
2. That battery status is "Discharging"

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following code in your manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".yourpackage.BroadCastNotifier" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In your `BroadCastNotifier Class`

```
package yourpackage;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BroadCastNotifier extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final static String TAG = "BroadCastNotifier"; 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();

        if(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW.equalsIgnoreCase(intentAction)){
            Log.e(TAG, "GOT LOW BATTERY WARNING");          
        }
    }

}
```

You will recieve the log message `GOT LOW BATTERY WARNING` when your battery is low, also try this in your device.

Although the above code might work the best way is not to use BroadCast for such actions, you can monitor the battery level as [described here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html). You can determine your battery with the code below which is way easier.

```
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

Comment: this will only work when not targeting the latest SDK

Answer (score 1):

The key is to **disable charging** with the telnet command

```
power ac off
```

If you then set the battery level to a low capacity

```
power capacity 1
```

the intent will be triggered

Answer (score -1):

You can register `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` in the manifest - see my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18946284/281545) - you can't register `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` in the manifest.

The reason you do not receive it is probably you forgot to declare your RECEIVER in the manifest

> Also if I have to call `registerReceiver()` inside an activity and I do not call `unregisterReceiver` on `onStop` or `onDestroy`, is it okay?

No. You should register in `onResume` and unregister on `onPause` ALWAYS - after `onPause` is called your receiver WON'T receive *anyway*

> If not okay, how will I register for a receiver to receive system intents even when my app is not in foreground? (Apart from using manifest).

Only in manifest

Comment: @tonygil: have you read the question ? I am answering _it_ - what's this nonsense about code ?