# Why the service starts on BOOT_COMPLETED but not with BATTERY_LOW?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, bootcompleted

Why my service starts on BOOT_COMPLETED but not with BATTERY_LOW? code:

MyScheduleReceiver.java

```
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    // Restart service every 30 min
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 30*1000*4;//1800000 ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent service = new Intent(context, service.class);
context.startService(service);
}}
```

service.java

```
public class service extends Service {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
      @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
      }

      @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
  mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
checkPref();
}
@Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

      }

private void checkPref(){ 
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                                service.this);
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Context");
                notificationBuilder.setTicker("TickerText");
                notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_icon);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, service.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                notificationIntent, 0);

                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(1,
                                notificationBuilder.build());
    }   }
```

and manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS">
<receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
     </intent-filter>

 </receiver>
 <service android:name="service" >
 </service>
```

Well the notification i want show with battery low doesn't appear.. if i change the action with BOOT_COMPLETED and i reboot the device works..why?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12348778/2508174

Looks like you need to programmaticaly subcribe to those intents too. And it looks like you don't need BATTERY_STATS permission to do it btw.

Hope it helps

Comment: Well,thanks.. later i'll try :-) . So with BOOT_COMPLETED doesn't need write the intent programmatically..that is strange :-)

Comment: Do you think it's the same for TIME_TICK?

Comment: Don't know, the better is to test ;)